# subdomains get ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED with traefik and docker-compose

Tags: wordpress, dns, docker-compose, traefik

I have a simple wordpress docker-compose setup that works on my main domain and is defined as such:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - /etc/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik
    networks: 
      - internal
      - test_network
  db:
      image: mysql:5.7
      volumes:
        - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      restart: always
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
        MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
        MYSQL_USER: wordpress
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
      networks: 
        - internal
        - test_network
  wordpress:
      ports:
        - "8001:8001"
      depends_on:
        - db
      image: wordpress:latest
      restart: always
      environment:
        WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
        WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
        WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
        WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      labels:
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:blog.example.com"

      networks: 
        - internal
        - test_network

volumes:
  db_data: {}
networks:
  test_network:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false
```

I get an ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED message in my browser when I attempt to visit blog.example.com but when I change the front end rule to

```
    - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:example.com"
```

it works as I expect it to. What am I doing wrong?

There's currently nothing in the /etc/traefik/traefik.toml and that file does not exist at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to configure the subdomain on my registrar/webhost. Once the A record was updated it started working.